# Is home parameter mandatory for MaterialApp even after defining onGenerateRoute?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is my App Wiget that i run from main.dart file.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(onGenerateRoute: _routeConfiguration());
  }

  RouteFactory _routeConfiguration() {
    return (settings) {
      // Map<String, dynamic> arguments = settings.arguments;
      Widget screen;
      switch (settings.name) {
        case '/':
          screen = UserLogin();
          break;
        default:
          screen = UserLogin();
      }
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => screen);
    };
  }
}
```

Unless i add home named parameter to MaterialApp, it's not loading UserLogin.
Without which it throws the following error stack.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MaterialApp /Documents/GitHub/flutter/demo/lib/app.dart:7:12

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _WidgetsAppState._onGenerateRoute.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:1196:48)
#1      MaterialPageRoute.buildContent (package:flutter/src/material/page.dart:54:55)
#2      MaterialRouteTransitionMixin.buildPage (package:flutter/src/material/page.dart:107:27)
#3      _ModalScopeState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:840:53)
#4      Builder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:7555:48)
#5      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4569:28)
#6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15
.
.
so on
```

Is it really necessary to have home defined even after route configuration defined?
I am new to flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to specify home parameter , you have to add your initial route like this

```
MaterialApp(
     // some properties ...
     routes: {
            "/": (context) =>  MainMenuPage(),
          },
)
```